# What is the use of poisoning pages in Linux and what does it mean to get page corruption error after calling check_poison_mem?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, memory-corruption

I am working on a device driver system and currently doing some log analysis after a crash that happened.   I find the following error in the logs.

**corrupted page:e5b06d60 pfn:0xc07eb is poisoned**

Also,

**pagealloc: memory corruption**

**ffeddd90: 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 .....**

**....**

**ffedde40: 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 .....**

1. What does this mean? What is poisoning and why is it used?
2. When I track the call trace, its goes all the way back to some memory allocation ioctls.  Why would memory allocation calls trickle down all the way to this error message ?
3. If the memory region under scan had indeed values other than PAGE_POISON, how it could have happened?
4. The PAGE_POISON is defined as 0xaa in the Linux Kernel (4.1.10).  Why am I seeing 80 ? Is '80' the memory corruption ?

Sorry if this is so trivial, I'm new to Linux and I couldn't find simple explanation for the need for poisoning and what's happening in this case.

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: Page management errors can have a delayed effect.

Comment: @0andriy: Umm, unfortunately no.  I mean, I can't add any code because of policy.  Moreover, the call stack is atleast 20 calls deep.

Comment: Then you on your own. Sorry, but you see the power of open source!

Comment: @0andriy. I understand. But what is poisoning a page in Linux and the need for it? If someone can speak on that, I'd appreciate that. I mean I'm looking for the conceptual explanation even if I don't get the answer for the errors I'm getting.  Thanks.

Comment: Page poisoning is a debugging aid. Pages are poisoned when freed and checked when allocated. So if it tries to allocate a page that isn't poisoned then something has been clobbering free memory.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Great. So after some free operation, the expected behaviour is that the memory in contention must be poisoned fully for it to be corruption free?  Also, if  the memory in question is filled with a pattern other than PAGE_POISON, then it must be corrupt, right? Like I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Rathnavel Yes, the memory must be corrupt.